# Kurento JavaScript Client- Cannot Create RecorderEndpoint

Tags: kurento, kurento-media-server

I am creating a RecorderEndpoint for my project using Kurento Javascript Client library. I have distilled the issue to something as basic as below.

```
var kurento = require('kurento-client');

var ws_uri= "ws://localhost:8888/kurento";

var kurentoClient = null;
var pipeline = null;

kurento(ws_uri, function(error, _kurentoClient) {
    if (error) {
       return;
    }
    console.log("Kurento Client created");
    kurentoClient = _kurentoClient;
    kurentoClient.create('MediaPipeline', function(error, _pipeline) {
        if (error)
            return;
        pipeline=_pipeline;
        //create RecorderEndpoint
        var recordParams = {
            stopOnEndOfStream: true,
            mediaProfile: 'WEBM_VIDEO_ONLY',
            uri: 'file:///tmp/test.webm'
        }
        pipeline.create('RecorderEndPoint', recordParams, function(error, _callerRecorder) {
            if (error){
                return;
            }
            console.log("Recorder Endpoint Successfully created");
            console.log("Program didn't crash");
            return;
        });
        
    });
});
```

A similar code works for WebRTCEndpoint (without Recording Params). I searched on the Internet and only found one old stackoverflow post and one github sample file. Both are creating the recorderEndPoint similarly. But it's possible I am missing something or the library usage has changed.

This is the error that is thrown.

```
Kurento Client created
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\MediaObjectCreator.js:58
    throw error
    ^

SyntaxError: Unknown type '[object Object]'
    at getConstructor (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\MediaObjectCreator.js:55:17)
    at createConstructor (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\MediaObjectCreator.js:74:21)
    at createMediaObject (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\MediaObjectCreator.js:140:23)
    at MediaObjectCreator.create (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\MediaObjectCreator.js:263:12)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\test2.js:26:18
    at callback2 (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\KurentoClient.js:530:7)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\KurentoClient.js:388:7
    at Object.dispatchCallback [as callback] (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:546:9)
    at processResponse (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:667:15)
    at RpcBuilder.decode (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\test\ReproKurentoIssue\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:723:5) {
  type: {
    params: {
      stopOnEndOfStream: true,
      mediaProfile: 'WEBM_VIDEO_ONLY',
      uri: 'file:///tmp/test.webm'
    },
    type: 'RecorderEndPoint'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. It's a case issue. The below call's first parameter is `RecorderEndpoint` and NOT `RecorderEndPoint`:

```
pipeline.create('RecorderEndpoint', recordParams, function(error, _callerRecorder) {
```